# Segfault Occurs After reserving a Larger Capacity for a vector<string>

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault, stdvector

I am trying to read words in from a dictionary file and I am receiving a segfault on my 4th line reading in from the file. From what I have read about vectors in c++ to use the insert command I need to specify an iterator to use as a place holder. To do this is I instantiate an iterator at the beginning of my vector as such.

```
 vector<string>::iterator it = dictionaryFile.begin();
```

Inside of my for loop I increment where the iterator is pointing by using the increment operator

```
it++;
```

I am basing this off of the examples on [www.cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com). The iterator works for the first 3 lines then the segfault occurs. I have double checked my file to make sure there are no erroneous characters that are being read in by getline. I believe this error has to do with the call to reserve that I make to ensure there is no overflow of the vector.

Since I am not using the keyword new when it is declared is the vector limited to a capacity of 5? I cannot find any examples of the new keyword being used though!

I have included the segment of code that causes this error. Please note I have re-designed this several times in an attempt to resolve this segfault and this was not my original implementation. I would appreciate any insight a master of c++ might have. Thank you for your time.

```
vector<string> dictionaryFile (5, "");                                                                     //Declaration of vector that will hold the words in the dictionary

ifstream input;                                                                                                  //Declaration of input file stream
input.open(inst.c_str());

/********************** Test to see if file was opened ********************************/                
if(!input){
    cerr << "The file " << inst <<" does not exists in this directory" << '\n';
}
/********************** File is successfully opened**********************************/

string temporaryProcessingString = "";                                                                //This string will temporarily hold values read in from the file
vector<string>::iterator it = dictionaryFile.begin();                                                 //Creates iterator to step through the vector and fix this wild shit

for(int i = 0; getline(input, temporaryProcessingString); i++){                                 //See I can follow directions given in class no eof used.
    cout << "Does this print before SegFault 1 " << endl;
    if(dictionaryFile.size() >= (dictionaryFile.capacity() - dictionaryFile.size()) ){       //If current size is greater the 50% capacity reserve size*2 more memory
        int oldSize;
        oldSize = dictionaryFile.size();
        cout << "Does this print before SegFault 2 " << endl;
        dictionaryFile.reserve(oldSize + oldSize);                                                  //Reservation new capacity for vector containing dictionary
    }

/** this is a test bracket that solely keeps track of the vectors size and capacity in the terminal COMMENT OUT BEFORE SUBMITTING*/
cout << "________________________________________________" << '\n';
cout << "Loop Run: " << i << endl;
cout << "Size: " << dictionaryFile.size() << ", Capacity: " << dictionaryFile.capacity() << endl;
cout << "________________________________________________" << '\n';
dictionaryFile.insert(it, temporaryProcessingString); /*******************************THIS LINE CAUSES THE SEGFAULT! UNFORTUNATELY IT IS ALSO THE LINE THAT MOVES THE DATA INTO THE VECTOR************************/
it++;
cout << "Dictionary Entry: " << dictionaryFile[i] << endl;

}
cout << "Dictionary Entry Primary Test: " << dictionaryFile[0] << endl;
```

Comment: I just want to say one word to you. Just one word.  [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Comment: How about printing "oldSize" when you hit the size increase...

Comment: I'm also pretty certain your iterator becomes invalid when you re-allocate the size of your vector. This may not happen the first or second time, because the allocation can be expanded "in place", but sooner or later, it will be invalid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When your vector's size approaches its current capacity (or, in your case, when you call `vector::reserve`, see the section on iterator validity [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/)), an internal algorithm will re-allocate it and potentially move it somewhere else, making all iterators to elements in the vector invalid.

As your program only seems to insert at the end anyways, use `vector::push_back` instead of `vector::insert` to prevent this. You can then also skip the `reserve`ing - the internal algorithms are quite good (you don't have to be afraid of the vector doing reallocation for every single new element - the algorithms are smarter than that).